# Retain or get feature names throughout a pipeline in sklearn (XGBoost Feature Importance)

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I am trying to get the feature importance for a XGBoost classifier but have no idea how to keep the column names throughout the preprocessing when using GridSearchCV.

What I tried:

```
model = clf_gridcv.best_estimator_
model.steps[-1][1].get_booster().feature_names
>>> ['f0',
    'f1',
    'f2',
    'f3']
```

I know how to get the actual feature names when not using an automated pipeline but since I want/need to use GridSearch, not using a pipeline is not an option.

The pipeline for reference:

```
   ColumnTransformer
-> StandardScaler 
-> VarianceThreshold 
-> SelectKBest 
-> Classifier
```